# Count Columns Where Date +7 days

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with roughly 30 columns that hold various dates for the user's deadlines.  I want to count the number of those columns where the date is within 1 week `(DATEADD(day, +7, GETDATE())`.

By way of simple example here is what the data might look like (I am assuming today's date is 7/16 for the `GETDATE())`:

#### Table

```
id     thisdate     thatdate    otherdate    userid_fk
1      2014-7-25    2014-7-18   2014-7-19    1
2      2014-7-17    2014-7-18   2014-8-15    2
3      2014-6-20    2014-7-17   2014-8-15    1
```

#### Desired Result

For user 1:

```
id    count
1     2
3     1
```

For user 2:

```
id    count
2     2
```

I attempted to set a variable and increment it using Case When and Set, but those apparently don't play nicely.  I also considered using a Pivot but can't seem to wrap my brain around that.

In response to ps2goat's request for an example of my botched query:

```
DECLARE @CT int = 0
SELECT id, SUM(CASE WHEN thisdate> DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE()) THEN SET @CT += 1 WHEN thatdate > DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE()) THEN SET @CT += 1 ELSE 0 END) as COUNT FROM dates WHERE userid_fk='1' GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Show us a sample query that you tried.  A very basic answer is to do a  `Select count(*) from mytable where thatdate between getdate() and dateadd(day, 7, Getdate())`.  I'm not sure what you need the id field for if what you need is just a count.  You need to clarify the question to get the proper answer that will work for your case.

Comment: @ps2goat I thought about that too, I could do 30 selects and then sum them all.  I'm no expert, but that seems inefficient.

Comment: Is the query supposed to be total for all users, or a total for each user?  You didn't specify that in the question...

Comment: Total for each user for each ID in the dates table.  So one user could have multiple projects they are tracking deadline for.  I want the count for each of those projects.  Does that make sense?

Comment: It's a sign of bad table design if you have *multiple* columns containing the same "sort" of data (such that you want to query them together, as here, or compare them with each other, etc). It usually indicates that this should have been modelled in a separate table with *one* column to hold the date and another column to hold the *data* that's actually become embedded in the *metadata* of your current table as part of the column *name*.

Comment: I think I see what you're asking, now.  How many columns do you have to check?  Is it just the two like in your example?

Comment: @ps2goat - first sentence of the question - "... roughly 30 columns ..."

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'm not above redesigning the table(s) but am not sure I follow your logic.  I have one table that tracks all of the dates.  Are you suggesting I should have different tables for each?  Ultimately I just want to tell the user they have X deadlines this week, then they go to a page where they see the list of deadlines.

Comment: No, I'm suggesting a single table with a separate *row* for each relevant deadline. I.e. user 1 would have (from your sample) 6 rows, containing `(this, 2014-7-25)`, `(that,2014-7-18)`, `(other,2014-7-19)`, `(this,2014-6-20)`,`(that,2014-7-17)` and `(other,2014-8-15)` (plus other relevant columns from your current design). At the moment, the *type* of deadline has been embedded into your column *names*, and the data is spread across multiple columns, which is making this query (and probably quite a few others) difficult to write.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever  I am showing my inadequacy on this topic.  The reason I have the table designed the way it is is because the dates are not required.  So one person could choose to fill in certain ones but not others.  I am not sure how I would cycle through multiple rows of data to assign the data to the appropriate textbox on my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id,
    (CASE WHEN thisdate BETWEEN getdate() AND DATEADD(day, 7, getdate()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN thatdate BETWEEN getdate() AND DATEADD(day, 7, getdate()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN otherdate BETWEEN getdate() AND DATEADD(day, 7, getdate()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count
FROM <YOUR_TABLE>
```